# Run some javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I am testing this simple code below and it works...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('.show-modal').click( function() {
        $('#modal-box').css( {
            left: $(window).width() / 2 - $('#modal-box').width() / 2,
            top: $(window).height() / 2 - $('#modal-box').height() / 2
        } );
        //delay(openModal, 500);
        openModal();
   } );

} );
```

However when I run the code below it does not, all I have done is removed the click event and I was hoping this would load on page load instead of needing a click event but it is not working.  Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

        $('#modal-box').css( {
            left: $(window).width() / 2 - $('#modal-box').width() / 2,
            top: $(window).height() / 2 - $('#modal-box').height() / 2
        } );
        //delay(openModal, 500);
        openModal();

} );
```

---

As requested, the openModal function

```
openModal = function () {
    $('#modal-box').show();
    $('#modal-mask').show();
};
```

Comment: can you show what `openModal()` does?

Comment: @NiftyDude I have added it above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mabye you need all resources to be loaded instead of just the dom. For this use:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // images and stuff will be loaded
});
```

Comment: if this fixed it, can you accept the answer so @yoshi can get the rep points. cheers!

Comment: @booyaa I always do, it makes you wait 10 minutes though

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

        $('#modal-box').css("left", (($(window).width()/2) - ($('#modal-box').width()/2)) + 'px');
        $('#modal-box').css("top", (($(window).height()/2) - ($('#modal-box').height()/2)) + 'px');

        //delay(openModal, 500);
        openModal();

} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Browsers usually block popped up modals when they are opened onLoad of a page. That explains why it works when you do it on click. Try disabling your pop up blockers.

Comment: It is a div and not a new Window. Only new popup windows will be blocked.